# White map-like tomato leaves (hydroponic) manifesting

Tags: diseases, tomatoes, pests, pest-damage

I am growing cherry tomato using kratky hydroponic method and ive seen these map-like lines manifesting on a number of leaves. I had to remove the infected leaves to control the infection if you will.

How can I effectively control this disease? 
Not that it is quite hot here in manila but the tomatoes are only exposed in morning sunlight and I havent done any nutrient replacement since day one.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Looks more like insects. Look at this page on leaf miners http://www.ipm.ucdavis.edu/PMG/r783300911.html

Comment: Thank you @OrganicLawnDIY for the feedback. The link is quite expensive but im not so sure about what pesticides to use something that isnt harmful for hydroponic plant.

Comment: They're resistant to some pesticides but that link I sent indicates spinosad is effective. Also check out this link which recommends squeezeing the leaves to crush them http://www.planetnatural.com/pest-problem-solver/houseplant-pests/leafminer-control/ Make sure you keep up with your nutrients to keep the plant healthy.

Comment: The leaf miner larvae are large enough to see, a needle with a little wrist action will destroy them and might be less harmful to the leaf than squeezing.